# Differences between dev tools (mobile) and mobile device

Tags: html, css, angular, mobile, sass

Layout using dev tools mobile[image: Dev Tools mobile]

Layout using (real) iPhone 8 Plus

[image: layout on iphone]

The wanted outcome is the first image (how it looks on dev tools)

```css
.linear-bg:after, .linear-bg:before{
 position:absolute;
 display:block;
 top:50%;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 max-width:600px;
 margin:0 auto
}
.linear-bg--quantity, .linear-bg--total{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#044571 20%,#2980b9 80%)
}
.linear-bg--2{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#b24592 20%,#f15f79 80%)
}
.linear-bg--3{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#432b58 20%,#734b6f 80%)
}
.linear-bg--4{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#904e95 20%,#e96450 80%)
}
.linear-bg--5{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#ff5f6d 20%,#ffc371 80%)
}
.linear-bg--6{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#ff9068 20%,#ff4b1f 80%)
}
.linear-bg--7{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#ffa000 20%,#ff5000 80%)
}
.linear-bg--8{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#b993d8 20%,#8ca6dc 80%)
}
.linear-bg--9{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#3ca55f 20%,#b5ac59 80%)
}
.linear-bg--10{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#2a99ef 20%,#52d9e5 80%)
}
.linear-bg--11{
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,#225e9e 20%,#712c69 80%)
}
.add-container{
 min-height:100%;
 height:100%!important;
 -webkit-box-align:center;
 align-items:center;
 -webkit-box-pack:center;
 justify-content:center
}
.add-container .content{
 background-color:#232e42;
 height:30%;
 width:100%;
 display:-webkit-box;
 display:flex;
 -webkit-box-align:center;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:space-around
}
.add-container .content .button{
 height:40px;
 width:80%;
 display:-webkit-box;
 display:flex;
 -webkit-box-align:center;
 align-items:center;
 -webkit-box-pack:center;
 justify-content:center;
 color:#fff;
 position:relative;
 font-size:12px
}
.add-container .content .button.edit{
 background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#2980b9),color-stop(126%,#6dd5fa));
 background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#2980b9,#6dd5fa 126%)
}
.add-container .content .button.add{
 background-color:#00e096
}
.add-container .content .button.add .icon{
 position:absolute;
 left:20%
}
```

```html
<div class="add-container col">
  <div class="content col">
    <div class="button edit" (click)="openModal('edit-modal', 'edit')">
      <span class="text bold" >Edit Inventory</span>
    </div>

    <div class="button add row" (click)="openModal('edit-modal', 'add')">
      <fa-icon class="icon" size="xs" [icon]= "['fas', 'plus']"></fa-icon>
      <span class="text bold">Add Inventory</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Also when i change `add-container` height from `height: 100%` to `height: 100vh` or anything with specific height it works.
What can affect the style from a mobile device to dev tools ?

Comment: Can you add compiled css?

Comment: @cloned yep added

Comment: created a snippet from your code, can't reproduce your problem. please edit it so we can see your problem and help you.